# Integration of Apple Pay With Android App Via NFC(Wallet Payments)

Tags: android, nfc, payment-processing, applepay

I am working on a POS wystem, which runs on android tablet(NFC enabled), in this app a feature is there to pay with Google wallet, which is working fine, now client has a new requirement to integrate apple pay also, i searched on Google and haven't find any good links that explain it is feasible or not, i am curious, is it feasible to pay via apple pay in android app? if yes then please provide some logic or useful links. Any helping hands Will be highly appreciated.

Comment: reason for downvote and close?

Answer (score 0):

**is it feasible to pay via apple pay in android app?**

I am not completely sure but, I am currently working on the same project and by using 
`private void resolveIntent(Intent intent)` , you can send a APDU command through NFC to an iPhone6 and receive a response.

If you can implement the APDU requestcommand to get hold of the PKPaymenttokendata/Carddata from the iPhone6 through NFC, you can process the PKPaymenttoken further and obtain the card data yourself in your server, or forward it to some payment gateway in little xml format and receive payment from them.

Read [this](http://clover-developers.blogspot.in/2014/09/apple-pay.html) to understand what apple pay is for developers.

You can use the payeezy's third party SDK to get what you want, i.e, to integrate apple pay within your own android app. 
`[https://developer.payeezy.com/sdk-downloads][2]`

There are so many such third party SDK's find them and make use of it -cheers!